# Main Window expect given a JDialog

Tags: java, swing, jdialog

I have a main window that calls a `JDialog` and **have to wait** on this data!

can someone give me a tip on how to stop code execution until the main q given that the dialog gets?

waiting and grateful!

### Edit

Managed to solve this: (for those who are going through the same choke that I spent ... sharing is never enough ! )

`JOptionPane` class blocks the application until the data is received ...

I made my `JDialog` received my `JOptionPane` containing the general `JPanel` (containing all that I want added to it)!

```
JOptionPane pane = new JOptionPane(panelGeral);  
   dialog = pane.createDialog(null, "Informe os dados solicitados:");
```

Comment: what's the ide you are using?

Comment: I suggest you to use intelij,it has an amazing swing support

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All JDialog has setModal property. If set to true , the user can not leave your JDialog and navigate to another window until the window closes . Another feature is that , thanks to this, the JDialog setVisible method also hangs and waits until the window is closed , like the JOptionPane does.

Answer (score 0):

As an alternative to setting modal, you can also use the static showInputDialog method, which is modal by default.

```
String foo = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null,"Informe os dados solicitados:");
```